# How to work with files in SD card on Visual Studio 2019 Android Emulators?

Tags: android, sd-card, visual-studio-2010, emulator

While I can see in a running VS 2019 Android Emulator that formatting the SD Card occurs on request, but I can get no further. How do I get files from the PC into it? The Android Device Monitor does list sdcard in its File Explorer, but clicking on the listing does nothing. Related: The Android Device Manager allows adding the optional property hw.sdCard.path but explains that to be a PC location of an .img file. How is such a .img file created and its contents updated?